# How to make a target_blank Menu link in EasyAdminBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

In EasyAdmin dashboard, i added a 'View website' link in the left menu:

[image]

But i would like it **to open a new browser window on click**. And I am wondering **how to add a target="_blank" attribute to it** (or any other solution to get this result).

For now i have this code in **App\Controller\Admin\DashboardController.php**:

```
public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
{
    yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fas fa-tachometer-alt');
    yield MenuItem::linkToUrl('View website', 'fas fa-eye', '/')
        ->setPermission('ROLE_ADMIN');
    // ...
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

->setHtmlAttributes(['target' => '_blank'])

https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Config/Action.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

```
 yield MenuItem::linkToUrl('Homepage', 'fa fa-home', $this>generateUrl('homepage'))
        ->setLinkTarget(
            '_blanc'
        );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to use **->setLinkTarget(string $target);**

It sets the target HTML attribute of the menu item link

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp , here are the HTML options for a link :

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

For your case it would be :

```
  yield MenuItem::linkToUrl('View website', 'fas fa-eye', '/')
     ->setPermission('ROLE_ADMIN')
     ->setLinkTarget('_blank');
```